# Under which category I can flag the Copy-Paste answers

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools, duplicate-answers

In stack overflow moderator tool, I saw an option like duplicate answer.

[image: Moderator tools]

I checked one of the example:

- ["Hello, WebView" tutorial opens the requested address in Android browser and not in my webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893815/hello-webview-tutorial-opens-the-requested-address-in-android-browser-and-not/17142916#17142916)
- [WebView link click open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser/17142898#17142898)
- [Android WebView click open within WebView not a default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser/17142881#17142881)

and found what that option is.

In the above links, you can find an answer from a user that have the exact content and wordings in all of the posts.

But I have one query. Under which category I can flag these answers ?

I usually use the **Other** category and add my comment. Am I correct or do I need to do anything more ?

[image: Flag options]

**My suggestion:**

It is very useful if there is a category called **Duplicate answer** (like Duplicate question) at-least in the moderator tool flagging options.

**EDIT:**

From the answers and comments,  I understand that it is a Community Moderator option. Please describe this in [privileges/moderator-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) of StackOverflow. So that everybody can understand it (Else they will ask it here and get down-votes like me ! :) )

Comment: From the above examples two of the answers deleted by the Moderator now. Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618316/how-to-create-a-pivot-query-in-sql-server-without-aggregate-function/17146622#17146622, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function/17146718#17146718)

Comment: Do you need to flag them at all? Can't you let a moderator deal with them?

Comment: Why the down-vote ? Can anyone explain the reason ?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Then Why it is displayed on the moderator tool of the other users ?

Comment: Historical reasons possibly? Maybe the fact that not much attention has been paid to the 10k tools over the last few years etc etc

Comment: I was thinking to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19571275/2284570) which was written  when unde undergoing bounty. I was afraid he won the bounty by duplicating my answer. hopfully, it has a benefit and I had enhance my answer for getting the bounty. My flag appeared in the `other` category. So it take too long and has been reviewed after the bounty period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Community ♦ flag. These are special, and are raised automatically by the system. If you find duplicate answers, use a custom flag (also comment requesting the user to write an answer in his own words).

Answer (score 2):

It's not forbidden to post the same answer to different questions. it is, however, a sign of a possibly duplicate question (although there may be cases when the same answer applies to multiple questions as well).

Upvote if the answer is good, downvote if it's bad. But a duplicate answer is not in itself bad.

Note, however, that copying *another user's* answer requires an attribution of the answer to the original poster, preferrably by mentioning their name and linking to the original post. Copying other's answers without attribution is a breach of the Creative Commons license used at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EmilVikström AND WHAT ABOUT writing a duplicate of an answer under a same question with an undergoing bounty and wining the bounty at the place of the original answer?

Answer (score 0):

"Duplicate answer" is an automatic flag (not raised by users, but if an answer is posted that is the same or almost the same as another, it will be flagged).

You are correct to use "other" in the case of blatant plagiarism.

Comment: @Doorknob In the case of a bounty question, the `other` catecory  is slower than the others categories... I've seen some case were the system don't make the detection. Creating a manual dedicated category would allow faster reviewing and won't do any harm.